# How to get a diff of changes between DefinitelyTyped @types package versions?

Tags: typescript, versioning, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

On npmjs.com I can see what versions exist for @types/... packages.

At github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped I can get the source code corresponding to those packages.

microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch links to the npmjs.com page.

However, I couldn't find a mapping between versions and commit hashes.

Where can I find those or where can I get a code diff between two versions?
Or maybe a change log?